# How to set firebug to only run on certain sites?

Tags: firebug

they keep chaning the firebug UI like ever week these days and I not really sure what happened to the option of enable firebug on "this page". It only has it for every website or no website.

It is really annyoing both of these options. Since every site I go to firebug comes up and gets in the way but if I have it off then I have to always remember to turn it on for my site I am working on then turn it off after.

I am using firebug 1.4.2

Thanks

Comment: try superuser for this question

Comment: Development tools are programming related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Firebug 1.4 Activation](http://blog.getfirebug.com/2009/07/20/firebug-1-4-activation/) and [How to enable and disable Firebug 1.4](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/how-to-enable-and-disable-firebug-14/) blog posts for the full scoop on the new scheme.

The basics are

> - One click to **open Firebug** on a web page, Ctrl+R to reload the page to see details in the Console, Script or Net panel.
> - One click to **minimize Firebug**, work with the page, one click to **reopen Firebug**.
> - One click to **close Firebug** on a page you don't want to debug after all.

That is, minimize FireBug on pages that you want it to keep analyzing and be available, close it for sites that you don't want to analyze again.  It should remember whether it was open or closed when you revisit:

> Firebug remembers active pages and closed pages. When the page starts to load, Firebug opens if the page was active last time. If a page was closed last time, Firebug will not open (even if the load was caused by a link from an active page).

Comment: How do you close it? I only see the off button and that does not do anything. I don't know why they could have not kept things simple and that worked well.

Comment: Use the off button to close Firebug for a domain (assuming you haven't unchecked Activate Same Origin URLs in the Options).  If you revisit a site on that domain and Firebug is open again, that's a bug, and you should log it with them.

Comment: Ya it does not work for me? Does it need something set. I have like clear cookies stuff at close. But even if I hit "off" and refresh the page it loads up again.

Comment: That definitely sounds like it's not working as it should.  Try asking about it on the Firebug Google Group http://groups.google.com/group/firebug, or posting an issue on their Google Code site http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/list.